# Object not available right away - why?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

### What I have

```
var testObject = {
    winter: ['january', 'february'],
    spring: ['march'],
    summer: ['june'],
    autumn: ['september'],
}
(testObject['spring'] || (testObject['spring'] = [])).push('april');
```

### What I expect to happen

`april` gets appended to `testObject['spring']`

### What actually happens

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spring')

And if I add any statement in between, everything works. Consider:

```
var testObject = {
    winter: ['january', 'february'],
    spring: ['march'],
    summer: ['june'],
    autumn: ['september'],
}
var what='ever';
(testObject['spring'] || (testObject['spring'] = [])).push('april');
console.log(testObject['spring']);
```

> (2) ['march', 'april']

Please help me understand why is that?

Comment: You forgot the semicolon on the `var` declaration

Comment: @Bergi Ahhh, you got it! Thank you! Would you post this as an answer, so that I can accept?